# Can you apply a Media Query specific style to an HTML element via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

Traditionally, you can use JavaScript to apply a style to an element:

```
document.body.style.color = "red";
```

But can you apply a media-query specific style in a similar way? What I'm talking about is this:

```
body {
  color: red;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
  body {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

The @media-specific style above. Can this be applied to an element programmatically via JavaScript? For example, I'd like to apply the above styles to the `body` element but without specifying any CSS. I'd like to do it all in JavaScript. Is this possible (in a cross-browser way)?

Comment: [This QuirksMode blog entry](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/08/combining_media.html) might be relevant.

Comment: [Here's an article](http://adactio.com/journal/5429/) about just such a thing.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I'm trying to apply a media-query CSS style to an element. The Adactio article is about using CSS and then querying the derived screen width from that. And the Quirksmode is simply about using `screen.width` as a condition. I still want my layout to adjust responsively as it's changed in size, I just want to try to apply the styles procedurally.

Answer (score 0):

Check the width of the window when it loads and when it is resized. Basic idea:

```
function resized() {
  var myWidth = 0, 
      myHeight = 0,
      color = "red";
  if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
    myWidth = window.innerWidth;
    myHeight = window.innerHeight;
  } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
    myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
    myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
  }

  if (myWidth <= 320) {
      color = "blue";
  }
  document.body.style.color = color;
}
window.onresize = resized;
resized();
```